# LFSR doesn't generate random values during simulation

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx, intel-fpga, lfsr

I am new to VHDL, but have some idea. I made this LFSR but don't know why it is stuck between the initial seed value and the other XOR value.
I am working with Altera Quartus 16 Lite and ISim.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

 --creating a galois LFSR
entity LFSR is
  port (
     clk        : in std_logic; 
     rst        : in std_logic;
     en         : in std_logic;
     rdm_out : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
     rdm_out_a : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
     rdm_out_b : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
     lfsr_Done : out std_logic --lfsr done
    );
end entity LFSR;
 
architecture behavioral of LFSR is
     signal temp_out  : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0) := (0 => '1' ,others => '0'); --initial value as seed
     signal temp_done : std_logic;
   
begin

  process (clk, rst)
  begin
    if rising_edge (clk) then --module operates only when enabled
        if (rst = '1') then 
            temp_out <= (0 => '1' ,others => '0');
            temp_done <= '0';
        
        elsif (en = '1') then       
        temp_out <= temp_out(15 downto 11) & (temp_out(10) xor temp_out(0)) & temp_out(9 downto 5) & (temp_out(4) xor temp_out(0)) & temp_out(3 downto 0);
      --temp_out <= (temp_out(15) xor temp_out(0)) & (temp_out(14) xor temp_out(0)) & temp_out(13) & (temp_out(12) xor temp_out(0)) & temp_out(11 downto 4) & (temp_out(3) xor temp_out(0)) & temp_out(2 downto 0);
        temp_done <= '1';
        end if;
  end if;
  end process; 
 
 
  rdm_out <= temp_out(15 downto 0);
  rdm_out_a <= temp_out(15 downto 8);
  rdm_out_b <= temp_out(7 downto 0);
  lfsr_Done <= temp_done;
end architecture behavioral;`
```

The commented out `temp_out` is actual feedback (taps are 16,15,13, and 4) as I checked with random taps but still no improvement.

And the testbench I used is this:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity lfsr_tb is
end lfsr_tb;

architecture test_bench of lfsr_tb is

component LFSR
      port ( 
        clk : in std_logic;
        rst : in std_logic;
        en : in std_logic;
        rdm_out : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        rdm_out_a : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        rdm_out_b : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        lfsr_Done : out std_logic );

end component;


signal clk1: std_logic;
signal rst1: std_logic;
signal en1 : std_logic;

signal rdm_out1 :  std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal rdm_out_a1 : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal rdm_out_b1 : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal lfsr_Done1 : std_logic ;

begin

mapping: LFSR port map(
clk => clk1,
rst => rst1,
en => en1,
rdm_out => rdm_out1,
rdm_out_a => rdm_out_a1,
rdm_out_b => rdm_out_b1,
lfsr_Done => lfsr_Done1 );

clock: process
begin
   clk1 <= '0'; wait for 10 ps;
   clk1 <= '1'; wait for 10 ps;
end process;

reset: process
begin
   rst1 <= '1'; wait for 10 ps;
   rst1 <= '0'; 
   en1 <= '1'; wait for 800 ps;
end process;

end test_bench;
```

This is the result I am getting:

[image]

Comment: Your LFSR is not shifting, it is a LFR (no S). Check once more, maybe, your understanding of LFSRs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it was not shifting but this is one is working now.

```
            temp_out(15) <= temp_out(0);-- shifting bit
            temp_out(14) <= temp_out(15);
            temp_out(13) <= temp_out(14) xor temp_out(0);
            temp_out(12) <= temp_out(13) xor temp_out(0);
            temp_out(11) <= temp_out(12);
            temp_out(10) <= temp_out(11) xor temp_out(0);
            temp_out(9 downto 0) <= temp_out(10 downto 1);
```

Hope it helps others. Thanks guys